# Does $\Pr[A\cup B] = \Pr[\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}]$ hold?

Tags: probability

> Does $$\Pr[A\cup B] = \Pr[\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}]$$ hold?

Here $\Pr[A]+\Pr[\bar{A}]=1$, $\Pr[A \cap\bar{A}]=0$, $\Pr[B]+\Pr[\bar{B}]=1$ and $\Pr[B \cap\bar{B}]=0$.

Comment: This does not hold.

Comment: The symbol $\cap$ is used in things like $A\cap B$ or $A_1\cap \cdots\cap A_n,$ and $\bigcap$ is used in things like $\bigcap_{k=1}^b A_k.$ I edited this question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A \cup B)=1-P((A \cup B)^c)$$

$$P((A \cup B)^c)=P(A^c \cap B^c)$$

Thus,
$$P(A \cup B)=1-P(A^c \cap B^c)$$

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not the same. Say we throw a (fair) dice. Let $A$ be even the number shown is $\leq 4$ and $B$ the number is even. So $$P(A\cup B) = {5\over 6}$$ and $$P(A'\cap B') = {1\over 6}$$

---

Correct one should be $$P((A \cup B)') = P(A'\cap B')$$

But this is true by basic set theory, namely $(A \cup B)' = A'\cap B'$ (de'Morgan Law).